# How Do I Call Snippets From Different Packages In Lift?

Tags: scala, reflection, lift

I am trying to call one of 2 snippet methods with the same name and same class, but these snippets are located in different packages. Here's the example code:

Snippet 1:

```
package v1.site.snippet

class TestSnippet {

  def test = { println("printed from v1") }

}
```

Snippet 2:

```
package v2.site.snippet

class TestSnippet {

  def test = { println("printed from v2") }

}
```

index.html:

```
<div class="lift:TestSnippet.test"></div>
```

So how do I tell index.html which TestSnippet.test to call?  Both packages have been added in my Boot.scala.

Comment: You can have sub-packages in your snippet package and then use `/` to refer to sub-packages. I don't know how to distinguish in your case though.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to differentiate in the snippet call, something like this: <div class="lift:v2.site.TestSnippet.test"></div> but this doesn't really work.

Comment: You could add the package root as snippet package and then do: `<div class="lift:v2/site/TestSnippet.test"></div>`. But it's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
LiftRules.snippetDispatch.append {
  case "V1TestSnippet" => new v1.site.snippet.TestSnippet
  case "V2TestSnippet" => new v2.site.snippet.TestSnippet
}
```

Your snippets must then inherit DispatchSnippet and define `def dispatch = { case "test" => test _ }` etc. You then invoke the snippets from the template as `V1TestSnippet` or `V2TestSnippet`.

Alternatively, something like

```
LiftRules.snippets.append {
  case "V1TestSnippet"::"test"::Nil => (new v1.site.snippet.TestSnippet).test _
  case "V2TestSnippet"::"test"::Nil => (new v2.site.snippet.TestSnippet).test _
}
```

I believe the List is the snippet name in the template split on dots.